# Jquery & HTML: Populating a text field from user input in jquery accordion panels?

Tags: jquery, html, tags, attributes, accordion

First of all, I am brand new to HTML and jquery.

I have the following HTML code with jquery code for an accordion drop down menu.
I am trying the following functionality: If the user wants to edit the question, the edited question should appear in the 'Enter Question' field in the top text field.

here is the output: https://jsfiddle.net/d0743rg2/

The code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">


  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    $(":button").click(function(){
    var text = $("#123").val();
    <!--var text = $('[name = "question"]').text();-->
    $("#input").val(text);
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<title> UI </title>

<center>
<form id="myform">
    <label>Enter Question:</label>
    <input id="input" type="text" name = "questions"/>
    <br><br>
    <input id = "submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</center>

<div id = "accordion">
    <h3> Question 1 </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            How many times a day do you take ventolin ?
            <br><br>

            <label for="in" name="question">Edit Question:</label>
            <input id="123" type="text" name = "question" />
            <br><br>
            <input type = "button" id = "edit1" value = "Edit" ></input>

            </form>
    </div>
    <h3> Question 2 </h3>
    <div>
        <form>
            Have you ever been tested for an STI?
            <br><br>
            <label for="in" name="question1">Edit Question:</label>
            <input id="in1" type="text"/>
            <br><br>
            <input type = "button" id = "edit2" value = "Edit" ></input>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can do the functionality (described above) using a unique id of the text field in the accordion panel.

I can do this for the first panel, but I have to use a specific ID ("#123").
If I want to do this for more panels, I don't want to have to write jquery code and make unique IDs for each text field for each panel. I want each 'edit'button in each panel to work the same.

My question is, how can I do this using a general attribute, so that when the edit button is pressed in any panel of the accordion, the specific text field in that particular panel is passed onto the main question text field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using ids, you can search through the DOM for your input fields:

For example:

```
var text = $(this).siblings("input[type=text]").val();
```

`this` returns to your clicked button, [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) are where your input lives.